# Mean and variance of sum of random variables with known contingent distributions

Tags: probability

Let $X_0, X_2,...,X_n$ be integer valued random variables ($0$ also allowed) with the property that $X_0 \geq X_1 \geq ... \geq X_n$, let $a_0, a_1,..., a_n$ be real numbers and $p_0, p_2,..., p_{n-1} \in (0,1)$ . Assume that $X_0 = x_0$ almost surely for some fixed number $x_0 \neq 0$ and that $X_j \mid X_{j-1}=x_{j-1} \sim binomial(x_{j-1}, p_{j-1}) $ for $j=1,2,...,n$ ( by "$\mid$" I mean contingent distribution). My question is, can anyone tell me how I calculate mean and variance of the sum
\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{X_0}\sum_{j=0}^n a_j X_j
\end{align}

Comment: It might be worth starting doing the calculation for $n=0$ (very easy), $n=1$ (fairly easy) and $n=2$ (more complicated) to see if there is a pattern

Comment: Can you show how to do the calculations for $n=1$ and $n=2$? I have tried to do the calculations myself byt can't get rid of the random variables I contingent on.

Comment: For $n=1$ $X_0$ has mean $x_0$ and variance $0$ so $X_1$ has mean $p_1x_0$ and variance $p_1(1-p_1)x_0$ and their covariance is $0$ so your expression has mean $a_0+a_1p_1$ and variance $a_1^2 p_1(1-p_1)/x_0$

Answer (score 1):

In general your expression has mean $a_0+p_1(a_1+p_2(a_2+\cdots p_{n-1}(a_{n-1}+p_n a_n)\cdots)))$ from the obvious pattern. The variance will not be so simple